# What is the meaning of out put of GP -I command?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

Below, you see the output of **gp -i** command :

```
gp :gp -i
Reader: ACS ACR122 0
ATR: 3B8980014A434F5032343252334B
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3B8980014

***** Card info:
***** Card CPLC:
IC Fabricator: 4790
IC Type: 5075
Operating System ID: 4791
Operating System release date: 2347
Operating System release level: 4100
IC Fabrication Date: 4198
IC Serial Number: 00174397
IC Batch Identifier: 4248
IC Module Fabricator: 4812
IC Module Packaging Date: 4205
ICC Manufacturer: 0000
IC Embedding Date: 0000
IC Pre-Personalizer: 143E
IC Pre-Perso. Equipment Date: 2830
IC Pre-Perso. Equipment ID: 31373433
IC Personalizer: 0000
IC Personalization Date: 0000
IC Perso. Equipment ID: 00000000
***** CARD DATA
GlobalPlatform card
Version: 2.2
TAG3: 1.2.840.114283.3
SCP version: SCP_02_55
TAG5: 1.3.656.840.100.2.1.3
TAG6: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.110.1.2
***** KEY INFO
Key ID:1 VER:255 LEN:16
Key ID:2 VER:255 LEN:16
Key ID:3 VER:255 LEN:16
Key version suggests factory keys

gp :
```

I want to know what is the meaning of this items?

Why I should know them?  In the other word, why gp tool developer, add **--info**(or -i) parameters to its software?

And also, what are different key versions and different key IDs for? Does having different Key version and Key ID mean, Different applets can use different Keys? Or the user can use different keys to communicate with the card? Or each Key has a specific role?

Comment: Have a look at global platform specification...

Comment: ATR is valid, but not very helpful. Card is identified as COP242R3, IC Fabricator: 4790 -> NXP: http://www.nxp.com/, IC Type: 5075
Operating System ID: 4791 -> JCOP - you need to find out in which version, GlobalPlatform version 2.2 -> http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested before: you can get detailed information from the GP specification. Consider `-i` a "dump data from card useful for debugging and other purposes". It dumps card data, CPLC and key template of the ISD. If you don't know what that means, read the specification.